# exception in InitialContext JBoss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

Estou a desenvolver um projecto em Java com JBoss. Eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
connectionFactoryLookupAddress = new String("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
destinationLookupAddress = new String("jms/topic/mC");
environment = new Properties();
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "isuser");
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "is");   environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "remote://localhost:4447");   
    InitialContext iCtx = new InitialContext(environment);
```

E eu recebo a seguinte exception

```
 javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory]
    (...)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
    (...)
```

Já adicionei o jboss-client.jar, e nada ... tenho que fazer algum tipo de configuração no servidor JBoss para aceitar este user? Estou a usar o Eclipse. Eu li alguns posts sobre este tema, mas não está claro para mim que configurações o JBoss precisa para executar este código. Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Porque você está utilizando org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory ?
Utilize javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory

Comment: Qualquer das duas opções o resultado é o mesmo: Cannot instantiate class: javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.InstantiationException: javax.naming.spi.InitialContextFactory]